# Why aren't Bootstrap 4.5 breakpoints working in my CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I recently started learning Bootstrap and I'm trying to figure out how to do two things with breakpoints: 1) make background color for headers and footers disappear at medium and large screen sizes, and 2) add text to the header at breakpoints using the content tag. I have no problem understanding how the breakpoints work in the HTML but any breakpoint styling in my external CSS fails to trigger any changes.

The media query in in question is `@include media-breakpoint-up(md)` - I just can't seem to make it work, even though the Bootstrap website tells me this is what I must use (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/).

I'm using the template stylesheet links / CDN and jQuery for Bootstrap 4.5 provided at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/ plus my own external stylesheet (responsive_styling.css):

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive_styling.css"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's the CSS from the external stylesheet:

```
header h1{
text-align: center;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header, footer{
  background-color:#0066FF;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md){
  header, footer{
    background: none;
  }
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(md){
  header h1:after{
    content: " Bootstrapped";
  }
}
```

Bootstrap classes in the HTML work as expected (e.g. changing display properties for sections at breakpoints) and the external CSS affects the HTML as expected, but those last two entries don't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

*Ben*

Comment: they are sass functions - not css - you would need to compile it to convert it into css

Comment: for your css, you want to use the `@media` ones in the page you link to first - choose the size and use the media query that corresponds - eg for your md, you would need to use `@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you, `@media` works! I'll have to find out about using sass. I also tried this using Bootstrap 3 and the code `header[class$=md]` but that didn't work either - is that for a similar reason?